# re.split on an empty string

Tags: python, split, python-re

I'm curious about the result of this Python code that does a split on an empty string `''`:

```py
import re

x = re.split(r'\W*', '')
y = re.split(r'(\W*)', '')
```

Since the string is an empty string, I expect the result for `x = re.split(r'\W*', '')` is an empty list and that for `y = re.split(r'(\W*)', '')` is `['']`.

The actual result for `x = re.split(r'\W*','')`is `['','']` and that for `y = re.split(r'(\W*)','')` is `['','','']`.

I don't know what leads to these results.

Comment: try to use `+` instead of `*`. I think `*` check also the empty match.  for the group: _"If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list."_

Comment: have a look at the last 2 examples in description of [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the regular expression `\W*` *can* match an empty string. Thus, while it's not *useful*, it's *true* that the empty string can be split in half to produce an empty string:

```
'' = '' + '' + ''
```

1. The `''` that *precedes* the regular expression
2. The `''` that *matches* the regular expression
3. The `''` that *follows* the regular expression

In the first case, you get strings 1 and 3.

In the second case, you also get string 2.

(In general, it's probably never a good idea to use a regular expression that can mach the empty string as the first argument.)

Comment: so any string can be seen as there are two empty strings at the beginning and the end correspondingly.
what's more,  when i see `re.split(r'\W*', '.')`, I can see `'.'` as `''+'.'+''`, so is it true that the second `''` and the third `''` will match the regular expression? I expect the result is `['','']` cause only the `'.'` matches the expression while the actual result is `['','','']` so i guess there is an empty string matched while i don't know whether the first or the third is matched.

Comment: There's only one "round" of matching, and we don't go overboard with saying something like `'.' = '' + '' + '' + ... + '.' + '' + '' + '' +...`. In some sense, `'' + '.' + ''` is the "minimal equivalent" that lets us match empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.split(r'\W*', '')` will give you 2 parts when splitting because `\W*` can match a single *position* in the empty string as the quantifier (the asterix) is 0 or more times.

Using `re.split(r'(\W*)','')` will give you 3 parts, because you are using a capture group `(\W*)`.

When using a capture group with [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

> If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all
> groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.